# rpcbind tries to contact scan-06d.shadowserver.org - is my laptop compromised?

Tags: macos, network, security, malware

Little Snitch on my laptop just caught an unusual connection attempt - /usr/sbin/rpcbind tries to connect to 216.218.206.83 (scan-06d.shadowserver.org). This looks suspicious to me as it has never happened before. How can I check why this happened? Are there any logs or command line utilities that can point me to the origin of this request?

macOS Sierra 10.12.1 (16B2555)

[image: Little Snitch window]

Comment: https://portmapperscan.shadowserver.org any help? There are similar organisations scanning for recursive DNS [I've just been tracing one incident recently] *Edit* in fact it's the same organisation. I was referred by my ISP - http://help.virginmedia.com/system/selfservice.controller?CONFIGURATION=1001&PARTITION_ID=1&secureFlag=false&TIMEZONE_OFFSET=&CMD=VIEW_ARTICLE&ARTICLE_ID=169605&buspart=uk_dm_b_na_security%20activity_na_opendns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is - no, my laptop wasn't compromised. Little Snitch blocked a scan attempt from [Open Portmapper Scanning Project](https://portmapperscan.shadowserver.org/) - it appeared that that rpcbind (a.k.a portmapper service) on my laptop is openly accessible from the Internet. I solved this issue by blocking all incoming connections for /usr/sbin/rpcbind (System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall > Firewall Options, press +, find /usr/sbin/rpcbind, select "Block incoming connections").

Thanks @Tetsujin for pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: That does mean it's getting through your router, though, which I'm not sure it should be.